# sweave; figure not portable

Tags: r, lattice, sweave

I'm a newbie to `sweave` and latex and I have a problem importing a plot figure in Latex.

I used the `xyplot()` from the `lattice` package. I did include `print()` in the code, but when I `sweave`, there is warning in R, saying "file name 'xxxx' is not portable.

My code is like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{center}

<< fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=

plot1=xyplot(Percentage~Age,type="b", group=Consonant.Type,data=m1,main="Lenition of /sm, sp, st, sg/ vs. others ",auto.key =list(lines = TRUE))

print(plot1)

@

\end{center}

\caption{Lenition of /sm, sp, st, sg/ vs. others by age}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: So....what's the file name? Sweave appears to just be checking file names against `.SweaveValidFilenameRegexp <- "^[[:alnum:]#+-_]+$"`.

Comment: strip that figure out of your main file, wrap it in a latex document, create some data in the chunk, and see if it still gives that error. That works for me.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks! Now the figure appears on the pdf! But how to get rid of the file name in the pdf. The file name of the figure is "age effects-003.pdf" and I don't want this to shown in the pdf.

Comment: @joran The file name is "age efects-003.pdf". is it because of the "-" in the file name?

Comment: Do you mean the filename is visible in the PDF next to or near the graph? Like in a caption or something? That would be odd, and we'd have to see the generated .tex file to figure out how that happened.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, just like what you said. it's actually in the space between the graph and my caption of the graph. really odd. and I don't see any weird things in the .tex file. anyway, although my problem of getting the graphs in the pdf file is solved for now, but does that mean I have to generate graphs separately each time I use the xyplot()? I still don't understand what's doing the weird work.